# SQLite: Number rows of query output

Tags: sqlite

I am learning SQLite and I am currently posing the question whether there is a simple way of adding a sequential numbering to the output of a query.  Underneath, I provide an example of what I am trying to achieve.

For instance, I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    splTicker AS 'Ticker',
    count(splTicker) AS '# of Splits'
FROM Splits
GROUP BY splTicker
ORDER BY count(splTicker) DESC, splTicker ASC;
```

The output of this query is as follows:

```
bash-3.2$ sqlite3 myShares < Queries/Split.sql
Ticker      # of Splits
----------  -----------
AI.PA       7          
ASML.AS     3          
BN.PA       3          
ALTR.LS     2          
BOKA.AS     2          
DG.PA       2 
...
SON.LS      1          
SU.PA       1          
SW.PA       1          
TEC.PA      1          
UMI.BR      1          
VIV.PA      1          
VPK.AS      1
```

I am trying to add a sequential number to the rows to obtain the following output:

```
#  Ticker      # of Splits
-- ----------  -----------
1  AI.PA       7          
2  ASML.AS     3          
3  BN.PA       3          
4  ALTR.LS     2          
5  BOKA.AS     2          
6  DG.PA       2
...
```

Currently, I use a workaround and add the row numbers post-query in Perl.  I am posing the question whether I could do this directly in SQLite.  The idea seems simple, but I have not found a solution yet.  Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards,

GAM

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Splits AS s2
        WHERE s2.splTicker <= s1.splTicker) AS '#',
    splTicker AS 'Ticker',
    count(splTicker) AS '# of Splits'
FROM Splits s1
GROUP BY s1.splTicker
ORDER BY count(s1.splTicker) DESC, s1.splTicker ASC;
```

Comment: I had tried something similar, but the query outputs the row number it splTicker occupies in the original data table -- before query.   The query returns 53 rows, while the original table contains 71 entries.